# Firefox steals focus from RocketDock

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, focus, launcher, rocketdock

If Firefox (v3.6.28) is running, RocketDock (with Layering set to "Always on Top") shows above Firefox but if in Firefox I do certain things (such as writing a post or watching a YouTube clip) RocketDock does no longer show on top of Firefox.

I also use another launcher (FSL) and when invoked that shows on top of Firefox while RocketDock does not... This problem only occurs with Firefox, while running any other application RocketDock pops up normally (on top).

I really hope someone can suggest a solution which DOES NOT involve add-ons installation (I do not want to cause sluggishness to the browser) or changing Firefox version (that for various reasons I prefer not to change).

I have tested Flashblock but beside the conflicts with Adblock Plus (installed) it does not solve my problem: RocketDock pops up normally but after allowing Flash content in a tab, RocketDock stays in the background (even after closing the "offending" tab and refreshing).

My version of Firefox does not have (nor responds to) plugin.click_to_play.

Uninstalling Adobe Flash is unfortunately not an option.

During the past days (since I suspected Flash to be the culprit) I have installed/uninstalled different versions of the Adobe plugin but without success.

I have tested this on 3 different systems (with the same OS/config) and concluded that ALL Firefox 3.6x versions (above v3.6.23) seem to be affected by that same problem :(

I have tested FF v15 and it does not have this particular problem but there are a number of other issues that I do not like and rather than an upgrade (with other headaches) I prefer to keep v3.6.28.

BTW (for those who are wondering):

Release date of FF v3.6.28 = March 13, 2012

Release date of FF v15 = August 28, 2012.

(Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_release_history)

Running Firefox with the "-safemode" switch (so deliberately disabling all installed extensions for troubleshooting purposes) does not help :( so I have also contacted RocketDock's dev to ask for support.

I am speechless that Mozilla keeps on changing stuff from version to version sometimes (almost purposely) creating STUPID annoyances and then fully rely on add-ons to solve them... It is like they are in a contest with extensions' developers to see who is smarter at creating/solving problems :D

Keep the suggestions coming :)

Comment: I would attempt to see if this problem exists in the current version of Firefox.

Comment: @ Ramhound: Please read my (edited) question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows wih Firefox. But the guilty party was, in fact, Adobe Flash. For some time now Adobe doesn't try anymore to make its plugin work better in Firefox. Even clips on YouTube that could be run with an older computer in the past, today can't be played well (on the same machine).

Anyway, if eventually your problem is like mine (I mean if the reason of lost focus is Flash) you can try the following (it's a bit of work):

1. install a Flash blocker like [Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flashblock/?src=cb-dl-users) (you can still run
   Flash when you want; but will stop Flash to run by default);
2. if you are familiar with `about:config` in Firefox you can stop
   Flash to run by default changing the value of `plugin.click_to_play`
   to true (I don't know if this property is available for your version of Firefox; if it's not available you can try to create it, but probably will be ignored by Firefox; so, you can skip this step and take the last one - only if you accept to be unable to run Flash in you browser);
3. and a last but more extreme solution: uninstall Adobe Flash and try
   to watch videos on YouTube using their HTML5 player (this solution
   it's not the best because there many clips that can't be run in
   HTML5).

To verify if Flash is guilty on your system you can try to replicate some scenario when you lose focus (captured by Firefox). If in those webpages you have some Flash, then Flash become "a person of interest". After that install Flashblock and reopen those pages. If everything is ok, then you're done. If not you can try changing `plugin.click_to_play` to `true`.

If even after you have tried everything here the problem persist, then you can be sure that it's not Flash the reason of stealing focus.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ CodeNighter: Thanks for your tips. Please read my (edited) question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this today - many of my windows were stealing focus from rocketdock, so I deliberately reverted it to 'normal' layering in the position settings.  When I set it back, window focus was no longer a problem.

Comment: Yes mate, apparently setting it to 'normal' layering in the position settings solves the issue!

Many thanks and wish you a great day ahaed